# CloudWatch Insights - Unable to display the "intent" value in display results

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to query the Results of the `resolvedValues` into my CloudWatch Insights, but I am not able to. Here is the queryies that I tried :-

```
fields @message
| filter sessionState.intent.name="Confirmation1"
| display interpretations.intent.slots.xcn_number.value.resolvedValues
```

And here is a section of the JSON data available.

```
   "sessionState": {
        "sessionAttributes": {},
        "originatingRequestId": "8d3423-d4234f-4234f-8e24321-234e2d7cdb7",
        "intent": {
            "name": "Confirmation1",
            "state": "InProgress",
            "confirmationState": "None",
            "slots": {
                "name": null
            }
        },
        "dialogAction": {
            "type": "ElicitSlot",
            "slotToElicit": "name"
        }
    },
   "interpretations": [
            {
                "nluConfidence": "0.71",
                "intent": {
                    "name": "Confirmation1",
                    "state": "InProgress",
                    "confirmationState": "None",
                    "slots": {
                        "name": null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nluConfidence": "1.0",
                "intent": {
                    "name": "xcn",
                    "slots": {
                        "xcn_number": {
                            "value": {
                                "originalValue": "0123456789",
                                "interpretedValue": "0123456789",
                                "resolvedValues": [
                                    "0123456789"
                                ]
                            },
                            "shape": "Scalar"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nluConfidence": "0.67",
                "intent": {
                    "name": "Q20ExtraMeditation",
                    "slots": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "nluConfidence": "0.61",
                "intent": {
                    "name": "Question2",
                    "slots": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "nluConfidence": "0.6",
                "intent": {
                    "name": "ServiceFeedbackQ1",
                    "slots": {}
                }
            }
        ],
```

The output remains blank. I need to access the `resolvedValues` and display it.